# Conilpotent coalgebras as pushouts of trivial coalgebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, coalgebras

Let $K$ be a field and $C$ a non-counital conilpotent coassociative coalgebra over $K$
whose underlying $K$-vector space is finite dimensional.

Question: Can one obtain $C$ by iterately taking pushouts of trivial coalgebras (= coalgebras with zero comultiplication)?
Especially, does $C$ belong to the full subcategory generated by trivial coalgebras under small colimits?

If not, can anyone give a counterexample?
Is there a natural condition on $C$, which guarantees that $C$ can be obtained that way?